# Access virtual attributes in mailer views - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a virtual attribute in my rails user model when someone creates their account. This is a hash. In the database, each user has another hash that is an encrypted version of this virtual attribute.

In my model, I have made the attribute `:attr_accessor` so that it can be called from other areas in the application. For example, when I send my newsletter I include this virtual hash inside embedded ruby like this:
`<%= @user.hash_name %>`
But it always returns nil. Is it possible to access these virtual attributes from inside the mailer views? I really don't understand why it isn't working because I have used the same mechanism other times inside mailers without failure.

Comment: When are you setting the value of `@user.hash_name`? As this is a virtual attribute (so not persisted in the database), you have to set the value before to access it.

Comment: @ZedTuX I set it before I create the user. Oh alright it will only work if I set it right before sending the newsletter.

Comment: Yes exactly. Let me post the answer so that you can accept it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A virtual attribute defined in a Rails model using `attr_accessor` is a field which is stored in the memory of the machine where is running the code, and is not persisted in a database.

This means that **this field will have a value only in the case you set it before to use it**, and only from the same machine (in the case in your production environment you would have many servers).

In the case you need to persist it so that you can retrieve it later or from another machine, you have to define that filed as a database attribute of your model by:

- creating a migration script in the case you are using ActiveRecord
- adding a `field` to your model with an ORM like NoBrainer or Mongoid for NoSQL databases